# syntax error near unexpected token `elif' on 2 levels if-else check

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I kept getting this error when I SSHed into my box.

```
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 65: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'                                                                          
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 65: `elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then'
```

This is what I have on these lines

```
if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
   # assume Zsh
elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    PS1="⚡️$yellow $dircolor \W $lightpurple $white"
    if [ $USER == 'root' ]
    then
        export PS1="$white┌──[$red\u$white@$red\h$white]──$white[$red\w$white] \n└── $white"
    else
        export PS1="$white┌──[$lightgreen\u$white@$lightgreen\h$white]──$white[$lightgreen\w$white] \n└── $white"
    fi
else
    # assume something else
fi
```

I'm only check if zsh/bash and set my PS1 accordingly.

Am I doing something wrong on my syntax ?

Comment: Because you `if` body is empty. If have no instruction add a `:` to just skip the `if`

Comment: actually that works in Zsh (and yash). But not in Bash, Ksh or Dash. @YetAnotherUser, want to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `if` body is empty. Try adding a dummy instruction like `:`,
or best, rewrite your code without testing for zsh:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    PS1="⚡️$yellow $dircolor \W $lightpurple $white"
    if [ $USER == 'root' ]
    then
        export PS1="$white┌──[$red\u$white@$red\h$white]──$white[$red\w$white] \n└── $white"
    else
        export PS1="$white┌──[$lightgreen\u$white@$lightgreen\h$white]──$white[$lightgreen\w$white] \n└── $white"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I like that .. it's cleaned. I will use this instead. What is this mean ? `Try adding a dummy instruction like :`

Comment: The equvalent of a `continue` inside a loop. It is used to do nothing.

Comment: @cyb3rZ `:` is a funny synonym for the command `true`, it doesn't do anything but the set the exit status. `continue` is different, it stops the current loop iteration, so the following commands will not run (they might run on the next iteration, of course)

Comment: Thanks guys! It helps a lot.